# How can I use moment() library inside a non-react module (for a React project)?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm not sure how to import moment() into my React project. I did `yarn add moment` but then can't access the library?

Comment: moment is deprecated switch over to dayjs it runs on the same api as moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used moment quite frequently. `yarn add moment` should do.

Next `import moment from "moment"`

Then you can call `moment()` anywhere in the file for example:

`moment().endOf("year").format("DD/MM/YYYY")`

Regardless, if it is a new project, consider [avoiding moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) and choosing a different library

Answer (score 0):

```
import moment from 'moment';

...
const Footer = () => {
    return (
      <footer className="main-footer">
        <strong>
          Copyright © {moment().format('Y')}
        </strong>
        All rights reserved.
      </footer>
    );
  };
...
export default Footer;
```

FYI, `moment js` is deprecated. Consider using other library, like `date-fns`